# Which statistical method to choose?

Tags: statistics

I want to to find out if the level of education has an effect on the answer to the question: "Do you think the climate is changing?"

My level of education variable has 3 levels and there are 5 different possible answers to the question (probably changing, definitely changing etc.).

I am not sure which statistical method is appropriate here

Answer (score 0):

This could depend on how you record your "climate change opinion" variable. If you keep it as an ordinal categorical variable, you could use ordinal logistic regression.

You could keep the variables both as categorical and conduct a Chi-Square Test of Homogeneity.

A path for more specific interpretations would be to assign a numerical value to this variable; such as definitely not changing = 1, maybe changing = 3, definitely changing = 5.

Your null hypothesis could be: "The mean climate change opinion is the same for each education level"
Alt: "At least one education level has a different mean climate change opinion."

You can perform an F-test of our 3 education groups to reveal if there is evidence of at least one group being significantly different from the others. From there you can use the Tukey HSD method to make comparisons between each education level group. This is like performing a t-test between each group.